# Unable to inflate the Search button in toolbar

Tags: android

I am having Navigation view and fragment container where multiple fragment are displayed my navigation view code is as below.I am unable to show search button in toolbar even though i'am trying to inflate the search button as below

```
@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);

        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }



<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:title="e-Vyapar" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
        >



        <FrameLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/containerView">


        </FrameLayout>
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:id="@+id/shitstuff"
            app:itemTextColor="@color/black"
            app:menu="@menu/drawermenu"
            android:layout_marginTop="-24dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</LinearLayout>




 <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.cdac.ayush.MainActivity">
  <!--  <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never" />-->


    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        android:title="@string/action_search"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView" />
</menu>
```

Any help would be appreciated Thanks.

Comment: Show your menu_main.xml code

Comment: edited the question with menu_main.xml file

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

**menu_main.xml**

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    android:title="Search"/>
```

Than in your activity in `onCreateOptionsMenu` do like this:

```
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);

         MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);

        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);

        SearchView searchView = null;
        if (searchItem != null) {
            searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
        }
        if (searchView != null) {
            searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(MainActivity.this.getComponentName()));
        }

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            Log.e( "SearchOnQueryTextSubmit: " + query);
            return false;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
            Log.e( "SearchOnQueryTextChanged: " + s);
            return false;
        }
    });
            return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

In Fragment you have to enable option menu in `onCreate` like this

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }
```

Comment: eventhough am unable to view the search button

Comment: Is Search visible in Preview layout of the menu in AS?

Comment: Are you doing this Search on Fragment or Activity and if its Fragment than you have enable option menu in `onCreate` i have edited my answer